# Passing the 'response' or 'data' AJAX return into a namespace function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, namespaces

I am trying to clean up my code by namespacing which is new to me. I have a very basic app that makes an Ajax request and then does a load of stuff with the response. The code is starting to look messy so I want to namespace it and then call the namespace function that takes the AJAX response as the argument. 
1. Can and should this be done?
2. If so how, here is the code

```js
var GETDATA = {
 myAlert: "this variable is the property of a namespace",
    // response?: ???? do i need to declare response var here somehow 
 
 myNSFunction: function () {
  alert(this.myAlert)
 }

 //theFunctionIWant: function (response??) {
  // takes the response from ajax request
  // does some stuff to it.
 //}
};


$(document).ready(function() {

  $( "#my-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  
     $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: "http://localhost:3000/DATA"
   })
   .done(function(response) { 
  
       //GETDATA.theFunctionIWant();
  
  });
                      
                      
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var GETDATA = {
    myAlert: "this variable is the property of a namespace",
    myNSFunction: function () {
        alert(this.myAlert)
    },
    theFunctionIWant: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-form").submit(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:3000/DATA"
        })
        .done(function (response) { 
            GETDATA.theFunctionIWant(response);
        }
    });                  
});
```

---

*Should you do this?*

Difficult to pass a judgment without understanding your overall goal and the scale of things, but mostly, no. You have to ask yourself, what benefit does this really offer? I mean, the handler could even be a function itself, not necessarily namespaced. What is the justification for namespacing it?

Will you have a group of response processing functions that are similar? Are you trying to build a store of received responses and related functions that act on the responses? Are you worried about conflicts resolution of some sort that requires a namespace to resolve with? etc.

---

A better approach: Consider closures for a private scope.

```
var RequestProcessors = (function() {
    var thisIsPrivate = "Ok",
        thisIsPrivateToo = "Fine";

    return {
        processorOne: function(resp, arg) { /* logic here */ },
        processorTwo: function(resp, arg) { /* logic here */ }
    }
})();
```

Comment: As this is the first AJAX call in this app maybe there is no great benefit. I may go on and add lots more functionality to this app, may 20 more ajax calls. If I do this should i not namespace each of them?

Comment: The app is intended to be a political fact finder, so there is a dashboard with the political parties and then lots of sections with the different areas of their policies, in each section is will allow the user to reference and compare the polices. Ex GET last 5 years data on employment, then compare with different party. As it grows the nunber of ajax request will to.

Comment: @IainWatt Like I said, at that scale, it could make sense, depending on how you see your grouping and relatedness of this request processing handlers. Also, it is considered useful to use a closure to hide the scope of your namespace. See the additional example.

Comment: Yes, I am worried about naming conflicts mainly, the response processing may be similar but as all the data is different I am not sure if I will be able to re-use it. I also want to store some of the  received responses for later use. My main concern is that of naming conflicts. As data may  be like var LabourPartyEmployment, var ConservativePartyEmployment.... and these will refer to same thing but NOT always the same data sets so I may not be able to re-use the funcitons. Also where would the AJAX call go in the example, thanks.